# NHibernate QueryOver, could not resolve property 'Foobar'

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

```
public class Base {
public virtual bool Foobar {get;set;}
}

public class MyClass : Base {
public virtual string Foo {get;set;}
public virtual DateTime Bar {get;set;}
}

var query = Session.QueryOver<MyClass>()
.Where(mc => mc.Foo == "Foo" ||  mc.Bar >= DateTime.Now() && mc.Foobar == false).ToRowCountQuery().Future<int>();
```

Anyone help with the error I'm getting, "could not resolve property 'Foobar'"
This query is one of several that will execute thus the Future usage.

Comment: I see issue, I'm trying to get Foobar from MyClass rather than Base. How would I joinqueryover given the 'or' restrictions ?